# PHP memory limit exhausted despite increasing

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, memory, pdo

I get the following error everywhere on my site:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 600 bytes) in /classes/database.class.php on line 22
```

I've attempted to increase the memory limit via ini_set and htaccess, but I still get the same error.

Raising to 128M for example results in an internal server error.

This is line 22 (and surrounding) of database.class.php:

```
private $host      = DB_HOST;
private $user      = DB_USER;
private $pass      = DB_PASS;
private $dbname    = DB_NAME;

private $dbh;
private $error;
private $stmt;

public function __construct(){
    // Set DSN
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
    // Set options
    $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    );
    // Create a new PDO instanace
    // line 22 now
    try{
        $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
    }
    // Catch any errors
    catch(PDOException $e){
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Increasing memory isn't always the answer to "out of memory" problems: you need to find out what is using all the memory and why (often it's a code error such as an infinite loop)

Comment: WHICH LINE IS Line 22

Comment: The problem is unlikely to be here, more likely to be somewhere in whatever instantiates your database class

Comment: RiggsFolly it's not significantly, because i think that it's not about PDO pdo doesnt waste lot of memory like that. It must happen in other script which waste lot of memory in reading from file or some loop.

Comment: the error says it's only trying to allocate 600bytes, so it must be somewhere else, but 60 mb isn't necessarily so much if for example image editing etc. is happening. you can check if the memory_limit change actually happened or was somehow prevented by the server by calling `ini_get('memory_limit');` after the set

Comment: I have lots of functions using this database class. Is there a way to find out which one may be causing this

Comment: @Kamil I realise that, but its not much help saying the error occured on line xx unless you identify line xx in the code supplied.

Comment: do you anywhere in the code use alot of memory? for imaging etc.? if not, then its probably an infinite loop. check every function that calls the constructor that you posted here, you should find the problem there

Comment: @x4rf41 no imaging no. I'll browse through everything and check for infinite loops

Comment: Look bellow try this, to resolve many new instances of PDO and connection. It will decrease unnecessary wasting memory.

Comment: Would there be something else in the code it could be other an an infinite loop?

Comment: if your code is actually working as intended then Kamil's answer should help for sure

Comment: Sprinkle calls to `memory_get_usage(true)` throughout your code, or set up XHProf which will generate a nice report for you. Unfortunately the error message itself just tells you the straw that broke the camel's back, not the lead weights it's already carrying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you getting this object for a lot of times change the object like this:

```
public function __construct(){
    $options = array(
                    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname,
                    'user' => $this->user,
                    'pass' => $this->pass,
                    'options' => array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
                                        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE    => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
                                      )
                    );
    $this->dbh = Db::factory("PDO",$options);
}
```

and than create a db factory class:

```
final class Db {
   protected static $dbInstance;

   public static function factory($adapter,$options){
       if(!self::$dbInstance){
           self::$dbInstance = new $adapter($options['dsn'],$options['user'],$options['pass'],$options['options']);
       }

       return self::$dbInstance;
   }
}
```

It will help, and decrease unnecessary wasting memory and your problem with many creating instance of PDO.

And update your memory limit in PHP.ini or using PHP:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","128M");
```

Comment: this is certainly how you should get PDO instances, because a php script runs single threaded, there is really never a reason to create multiple connections to the same database, but i still think the problem is somewhere else (you would have to call the constructor A LOT of times to reach 60MB+)

Comment: He told that he has lot of functions with use the objects, so problem it can be here because if he creating lot of instances at the same time, it can waste all memory. We don't know his code so he can have a loop with updates where he create instance for any loop.

Answer (score 0):

In the error message `67108864 bytes = 65Meg`. So I would suggest that however you think you increased the memory limit to 128M it did not work.

If you get an internal server error when you try and increase the limit then you are probably using an incorrect syntax.

The syntax to use in the .htaccess file is :-

```
php_value memory_limit 128M
```

The syntax to use in the your PHP Script is :-

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
```